# more than one profile in asp classic

Tags: session, asp-classic, profile

I'm working in asp classic, my code saids that if the user has the profile "8" could see
  a  report, but now I need that for all profiles, I thougth that if I put: 
    if Session("id_perfil") <= "8" then...
  but doesn´t works, in this moment the code is:
    if Session("id_perfil") <> "8" then...
  I know that must be something very stupid but I'm stuck on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: This question looks like it might be relevant to SO but its so poorly written its difficult decipher.  More text is needed to give us a chance at decoding the question.

Answer (score 1):

my problem is that I was writing 
    if Session("id_perfil") <= "8" then
    'ASegm4(k,1)="Edición"

and the rigth way is:

```
if Session("id_perfil") =< "8" then    
'ASegm4(k,1)="Edición"
```

I said "must be something very stupid..."